# Continuity of a current through an inductor

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor

According to [this website](https://spinningnumbers.org/drafts/continuity.html),
the current through an inductor is always continuous unless there is an infinite voltage or current.
but

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYT0np.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now I know that the circuit was working before t=0 so the current on \$ i_{L1}(0^-)=10[A] \$ and \$ i_{L2}(0^-)=0[A]\$ and at t=0 they are connected in series so \$ i_{L1}=i_{L2} \$ so at least one of them has to be discontinuous.

Where is this "infinite voltage" coming from?

Comment: In the real world, you'd get an arc across the switch as the current in the second inductor begins to increase.

Comment: and in the ideal world? how should i approach this?

Comment: The ideal world doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do was to replace the switch with a constant current source (\$ I(t)=10(1-u(t)) \$) and then use derivative as a delta function and solve the differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

> *so where is this "infinite current" coming from?*

Well, I'm sad to report that it appears to be coming from your imagination. This is because the website you linked doesn't relate infinite current with an inductor at all. However, it does say this: -

> **The principle of continuity of capacitive voltage says: In the absence
> of infinite current, the voltage across a capacitor cannot change
> instantaneously.**
>
> **The dual of this is the principle of continuity of inductive current:
> In the absence of infinite voltage, the current through an inductor
> cannot change instantaneously.**

In other words, it talks about infinite current in the context of a capacitor but, it only talks about infinite voltage in the context of an inductor.

---

After a question amendment by the OP....

> *so where is this "infinite voltage" coming from?*

It's coming from this equation: -

$$V = L\cdot\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

You have created a current discontinuity by opening SW3 and that means \$\frac{di}{dt}\$ becomes infinite and that means the voltage has to become infinite.

Comment: thanks, i edited my question

Answer (score 0):

As you have observed, the current through an ideal inductor must be continuous, as an instantaneous change in current implies an infinite voltage across at least one of the inductors.

This is similar to problems that begin with two ideal capacitors charged to different voltages, and those capacitors are suddenly connected in parallel.

In both cases the answer is that such circuits can not be solved as valid circuit problems. They violate our assumptions about how ideal components behave and what it means for elements to be in series or parallel. To make this a solvable circuit you need a path for current **around** one of the inductors. At \$t=0+\$ that path will have a current equal to the difference in the inductor currents.

Comment: Mmm the current after the discontinuity will not be the difference in inductors current, but taking a little further the duality with capacitors you correctly highlight, we just need to change the conserved quantity. With capacitors it's charge, C×V while with inductors it's flux L×I which must be conserved.

Comment: @carloc Maybe you misunderstood...we need a current path that does not have a discontinuity. And conserving charge or flux doesn't fix the problems with KVL, KCL, and our definitions of parallel and series. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_capacitor_paradox

Comment: No misunderstanding, parallel capacitors conserve change and series inductors flux, no matter continuity or not, the paradox arises only because in both cases energy is not conserved. Nonetheless charge/flux conservation is what you need to quickly solve state variable discontinuity. This comes from pushing analysis to the limit where the continuous case becomes Dirac's delta ruled. The missing energy is not accounted by this model, as usual, pushing reality into limit cases is tricky.